# How to test website in IE11 compatibility?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-11

I have make a wordpress website http://thecloudmouth.com. by used Twitter bootstrap 3.0. It work all browsers without Internet Explorer 11. It is really very frustration for me. Please give me solutions. How to check IE11 from online or use any software ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft provides [several tools](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools) for testing different versions of IE.  They even have an IE11 Preview VM.

Answer (score 6):

You can download free virtual machines from http://modern.ie.

One of the VMs available includes IE11.

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

That should get you what you need to test it, and best of all, it's free.

Comment: second link is broken as of March 2019